# Cannot access deployed meteor mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, deployment

I deployed a site onto meteor and I am having trouble accessing the database from my command line. I keep getting the error:

`Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed`

The steps I took:

`meteor login`

Enter meteor username & pw

`meteor mongo myappname.meteor.com`

I get the error:

`Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed`

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!